# Sort HasMap List

Tags: android, listview, sorting, hashmap

I have google'd it, and tried some examples, but I always get stuck.

This is the error message, when I try to use the `Collections.sort`:

> The generic method `sort(List<T>)` of type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments (`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`). The inferred type `HashMap<String,String>` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

My code is similar to this one.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//Get the data (see above)
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

try {
    //Get the element that holds the earthquakes ( JSONArray )
    JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

    //Loop the Array
    for (int i = 0; i < earthquakes.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

        map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
        map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
        map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " + e.getString("magnitude"));
        mylist.add(map);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.main,
        new String[]{"name", "magnitude"},
        new int[]{R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You don't show the code where you call `Collections.sort(...)`...

Comment: Hi assylias. Thanks for your reply. That is my main problem. I dont know where to put it. And if i have to change the ArrayList or not. Because of that, i put a clean code, rather than a mess code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained by @pcalcao, you need to decide how you are going to sort the maps (based on what criteria), then implement that sort order in a custom comparator and call Collections.sort with that comparator.

For example, let's say you want to sort by alphabetical order of names, you would write something like:

```
Collections.sort(mylist, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        String name1 = o1.get("name");
        String name2 = o2.get("name");
        if (name1 == null) return -1;
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
});
```

Comment: I get it to work now. Now i know what was mess my previous try´s. I don´t put the "<Map<String, String>>" on the Comparator. Thank you very much. Now i have the list sorted by the Date of the item. And it a start, to sort for more items if i want. :)

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because you cannot simply compare two instances of HashMap.

When you invoke the `sort` method on a List, Java will try and compare each of the elements to each other and order the collection. If the elements cannot be compared (there is no obvious way of comparing two HashMaps, what would be the criteria?), that error occurs.

Do you really need to have that list sorted? If so, by which criteria?

The only way of achieving this would be for you to create your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use it to compare instances of HashMaps taking your specific criteria into consideration.

Comment: the right way of thanking is by accepting the answer ;) I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Tell just one thing, please...so i dont have to change nothing, like the arraylist,or something like that, but just create a comparator, with the item i want to sort, is that ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a Comparator class that compares two HashMaps, and use that as the argument of your sort. Read that small article on Comparators and you'll get the picture =)

Comment: I get it to work now. Now i know what was mess my previous try´s. I don´t put the "<Map<String, String>>" on the Comparator. Thank you very much. Now i have the list sorted by the Date of the item. And it is a start, to sort for more items if i want. :)